# Memsql Auto Increment

Tags: singlestore

I'm new to Memsql. I'm facing a problem with Memsql auto increment.

I created a new table with `id(auto increment=1)`. While insert manually using insert command it's showing `id(auto increment) 1`, but while using spark it's starting from 48,413,695,994,232,833.

In spark I'm creating dummy data `val test = Seq(("Test1", "600482", "46987"),("Test2", "600204", "4870A"),("Test3", "600204", "469870A")).toDF("confid", "confidprefix","salesid")`.

I used memsql-connector_2.11-2.0.4.jar,memsql-connector_2.11-2.0.2.jar.

Comment: We've experienced this when removing the master aggregator and letting the child take over.
This does not work well with javascript as the max number value in js is 9007199254740991 which is less that the memsql auto incremented number.

Answer (score 0):

In MemSQL, auto_increment only guarantees that automatically generated values are unique - not that they are sequential like 1, 2, 3... See https://docs.memsql.com/sql-reference/v6.0/create-table/#auto-increment-behavior

Comment: Thanks, i go through the link, but i one question, i have two cluster one have 3 nodes, and another one have 5 nodes. In that 5 nodes cluster only i have that problem, in 3 nodes  cluster i does't have any problem with auto increment.

Comment: Like I said, it's not a problem per se, it's simply the design of auto_increment in MemSQL. You cannot rely on auto_increment values starting from 1. If you need such functionality, you will need to generate the values yourself on the application side. The specific values generated depend on the number of aggregator nodes, which is why you would see different values in differently sized clusters.

Answer (score 0):

In my 5 nodes memsql cluster i have 2 Aggregator nodes, Master Aggregator and Child Aggregator.
Now i just removed that Child Aggregator from my memsql cluster and now working fine. Its generating auto increment id correctly.
**Note** that the automatically generated values can differ depending on which aggregator you run the inserts on. Of course, if you ran some inserts on one aggregator and some inserts on another aggregator, you would get different automatically generated values. Also note that automatically generated values and explicitly set values can collide.